# Matching values based on row number

Tags: r, vector

I have 2 equally sized vectors as follows

```
x <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
y <- c(8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,9)
```

I want to know that in the value that is same in x and y at the exact position in both vectors

my output should be 4, 9  because in both vectors at the 5th position the number 4 exist and 10th position 9 exist

How can I go about it

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do:

```
x[x == y]

[1] 4 9
```

It checks whether "x" is the same as "y":

```
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

and then subsets "x" if TRUE.